# Add some sheetname to excel using pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have data

```
      date               mail                 request
2016-06-17 13:27:49 yans.bouts@yandex.ru    GET HTTP/1.1
2016-06-17 13:30:46 yans.bouts@yandex.ru    GET HTTP/1.1
2016-06-17 12:05:04 titovtanya@yandex.ru    GET HTTP/1.1
2016-06-17 12:05:28 titovtanya@yandex.ru    GET HTTP/1.1
2016-06-17 12:18:36 titovtanya@yandex.ru    GET HTTP/1.1
```

I need to create empty excel file with every name from `mail` and add to this `sheet1`, `sheet2`, `sheet3`, `sheet4`.
I use

```
df.groupby('mail').apply(lambda g: g.to_excel(g.name + '.xlsx', u'sheet1'))
```

but it's creating files with data(I need in empty) and only `sheet1`
What I should do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `g.to_excel` which is supposed to put data in the file.

Instead, create an empty dataframe and use it with `to_excel`.

```
edf = pd.DataFrame()

f.groupby('mail').apply(lambda g: edf.to_excel(g.name + '.xlsx', u'sheet1'))
```